# Is the S-procedure or S-lemma valid for nonquadratic inequalities?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, linear-matrix-inequality

The s-procedure or s-lemma tries to solve a system of quadratic inequalities via a linear matrix inequality (LMI) relaxation. There are many different enunciations and if you are not sure what i mean you can check [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/S003614450444614X).

I have seen it be used in papers where the inequalities are not quadratic, for example [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0020025521004448?via%3Dihub), but I cannot find a form of the theorem that seems to apply. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.